# How to interpret a meta-regression output?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I've conducted meta-regression analyses using the 'metafor' package in R. I am trying to interpret the outputs if you could please help?

Output 1 (categorical with 3 levels): Test of moderator is significant, but the individual variables are not significant. Can I say that there was no significant association? Or should I report that the test is significant but variables were not?

Output 2 (categorical with 3 levels): The test of moderator is not significant but the intercept is significant, how can I report this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Output 1: is your moderator a categorical one with more that two levels? Output 2: what do you mean by "the other variable"?

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information rather than replying in a comment as comments are often ignored by readers.

Comment: Thanks - just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

With three (or more) levels the individual tests to which you refer each compare one level to the reference level (assuming that is the parameterisation you chose). The overall test reports whether there is any difference between the levels which is not the same.

For the two level case then the options I outline for the three level case boil down to the same thing so they will always give the same result as one another.

The test of the intercept tests whether it is different from zero. This is very often not of any scientific interest.